# ArcGIS Mapview in ScrollView map scrolling issue

Tags: android, dictionary, scrollview, arcgis, esri

I've been looking through a bunch of the different topics about issues with the ScrollView stealing the touch events from a MapView with google maps and I've seen several different solutions on how to override the onTouch event.  I am using ArcGIS maps for my app and I have tried several of the google map solutions and nothing has worked.  So I'm wondering if anyone out there might have a solution that would work with the ArcGIS mapview in a ScrollView to override the onTouch event so that the map can be panned both vertically and horizontally.

Currently I only have the MapView with a couple of layers added to it, so it's a very basic setup, but if posting some of the code will help I'll be more than happy to post some of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Came up with a solution that works.

I put the listener in the onCreate for the activity.

```
MyTouchListener tl = new MyTouchListener(this, mMapView);
    mMapView.setOnTouchListener(tl);
```

Then I created a class within the same activity that extends the MapOnTouchListener class.

```
    class MyTouchListener extends MapOnTouchListener{

            ScrollView sv;

    public MyTouchListener(Context c, MapView m){
        super(c, m);
    }

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
        sv = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scroll);
                    int action = event.getAction();
        switch(action){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            // will disable the scrollview from being able to 
                            // intercept the touch events for the mapview
                            sv.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                            // gives control back over to the scrollview
            sv.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
            break;
        }

        super.onTouch(v, event);
        return true;
    }


}
```

I hope this will help someone out and save them the hours I spent trying to find what I was looking for.